# Ruby on rails - How can check a radio button, created by simple form, is checked in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I built an view to create question and answer. This is my Question and Answer model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question_type
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :question
end
```

My answer model also have a attribute called `correct` type boolean to set true if which answer is correct, default is false. I have built a form to create a True/False question:

```
<%= simple_form_for @question do |q| %>

  <%= q.input :content, input_html: { rows: 3, class: 'span6' } %>
  <%= q.input :mark, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>
  <%= q.association :topic %>
  <%= q.association :question_type %>

  <%= q.simple_fields_for :answers do |a| %>

    <%= a.input :correct, collection: [[true, 'True'], [false, 'False']],
                                                            as: :radio_buttons,
                                                            label: 'Answer',
                                                            value_method: :first,
                                                            label_method: :last,
                                                            item_wrapper_class: 'inline'
                                                            %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The correct attribute when rendered in view have these html:

```
<label class="radio inline"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="question_answers_attributes_0_correct_true" name="question[answers_attributes][0][correct]" type="radio" value="true">True</label>

<label class="radio inline"><input checked="checked" class="radio_buttons optional" id="question_answers_attributes_0_correct_false" name="question[answers_attributes][0][correct]" type="radio" value="false">False</label>
```

Now in controller i want to check which radio button is checked and its value. Is there any method to check if `correct` attribute is checked and its value in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the params[:question][:answers_attributes] to check radio button checked or not. You can do something like this,

```
params[:question][:answers_attributes].collect do |answer_attribute|
     answer_attribute if answer_attribute.last["correct"] == true
end.compact
```

This will return an array of answer attributes which are corrected as true.

Answer (score 2):

the `params[:question][:answers_attributes][0][:correct]` will have value as either true or false. Since the `params[:question][:answers_attributes][0][:correct]` has only one value. You can find which value the user has selected.

Only the selected radio button's value gets sent to the server.

Comment: So if i have many answers, how i check which radio buttons is checked?